# The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. I cannot add the reference?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

In Visual Studio (same issue in 2013 & 2015 Editions), I am getting this error when building my project:

```
The type 'DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0
```

I am doing this as I would like to use the `MySQL.Data` package, but it seems to require `System.Data`.

However, in my project there is no way to add `System.Data` to my references, it is not in the list of references so I cannot 'tick' it to add it to the project. This is a `Xamarin C#` solution, and the project that does not list `System.Data` is a PCL.

Does this affect the packages? If so, is there some way to work around this or get MySQL.Data working without this?

Comment: try https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better approach is to not connect from your application directly to the database (`2-tier`), but define a `Web service` to consume and that Web service will connect to the database (`3-tier`).

Thus, `Xamarin C#` does not require reference to System.Data. One option is to use `JSON` as a data format for communication.

More details about this problem are discussed [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46459/xamarin-android-connection-with-mysql-databae).

Comment: I should have mentioned that, yes, this is a much better process (and it's one I have used for a larger application). However, I am developing a small personal app at the moment and am wanting to connect to a db directly for ease of use. It will take a lot of time to parse all the `JSON` responses so I was hoping to connect directly in this situation.

Comment: It is tempting to have such approach for small applications, but a small application is also a good opportunity for learning various frameworks and patterns. In this case, serializing and deserializing JSON, maybe auto mapping from data models to service models.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i solved it by just upgrading my project .Net Framework to 4.5.

I got this issue when using Postgres Driver (Npgsql) which requires at least this framework version.